# How to start working with Oracle NoSql Database?

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle-nosql, nosql

I want to take a look at NoSql DB and try to create it with following instructions https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26161_02/html/AdminGuide/install-config.html

And.. I have an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sleepycat/je/CacheMode

at oracle.kv.impl.param.Parameter.createParameter(Parameter.java:205)
at oracle.kv.impl.param.DefaultParameter.create(DefaultParameter.java:49)
at oracle.kv.impl.param.ParameterState$3.putState(ParameterState.java:1064)
at oracle.kv.impl.param.ParameterState$3.<init>(ParameterState.java:1334)
at oracle.kv.impl.param.ParameterState.<clinit>(ParameterState.java:1032)
at oracle.kv.impl.param.Parameter.createParameter(Parameter.java:229)
at oracle.kv.impl.param.ParameterMap.setParameter(ParameterMap.java:450)
at oracle.kv.impl.param.ParameterMap.setParameter(ParameterMap.java:435)
at oracle.kv.impl.admin.param.BootstrapParams.<init>(BootstrapParams.java:119)
at oracle.kv.impl.util.KVStoreMain$MakeConfigParser.verifyArgs(KVStoreMain.java:755)
at oracle.kv.impl.util.CommandParser.parseArgs(CommandParser.java:317)
at oracle.kv.impl.util.KVStoreMain.makeBootConfig(KVStoreMain.java:570)
at oracle.kv.impl.util.KVStoreMain.access$100(KVStoreMain.java:79)
at oracle.kv.impl.util.KVStoreMain$2.run(KVStoreMain.java:210)
at oracle.kv.impl.util.KVStoreMain.main(KVStoreMain.java:472)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sleepycat.je.CacheMode
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

My command is

```
java -jar /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/lib/kvstore.jar makebootconfig -root /home/oracle/KVROOT \
                                                  -port 5050 \
                                                  -admin 5051 \
                                                  -host localhost \
                                                  -harange 5010,5020 \
                                                  -capacity 1 \
                                                  -num_cpus 1 \
                                                  -memory_mb 1000 \
                                                  -store-security none
```

Can somebody help me to join nosql world, please?

Comment: this class should come from dependent lib located in the same directory as kvstore.jar. Make sure there is `je.jar` in the `/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/lib` (and all other jars from distributive as well)

Comment: If you just want to 'join' the NoSQL world there are many simple low-cost options. I have personally found Neo4J to be very interesting and its easy to set up, has a web client front-end and SQL-like queries. Certainly much easier than Oracle if you just want to check something out.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev thanks, it helped, but on the step 4 I still have error with noclassdeffounderror org/codehaus/jackson/jsonnode. I need to download some jar files again?

Comment: @BriteSponge I'll check them out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your sqldeveloper is an older version. Suggest you download Oracle NoSQL from the link below and try the same step, I tried [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/nosqldb/downloads/index.html) and it worked.

Oracle NoSQL is also available on [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/oracle/nosql/), if you prefer that way,

note - Oracle NoSQL is certainly low cost, given that the community edition is free and licensed under Apache-v2.